# Debuging C on Mac OS Sierra

Tags: c, macos, debugging, valgrind

I currently have Mac Sierra 10.12.3 and I had the surprise that Valgrind is not compatible despite their latest version.

```
valgrind: mmap-FIXED(0x0, 253952) failed in UME (load_segment1) with error 12 (Cannot allocate memory).
```

I wanted to know if there was a solution to solve this problem or another debugger (gdb does not work either).
I prefer not to use XCode because I like to program with a terminal.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use LLDB as described in this article http://www.developerfiles.com/debugging-c-with-clang-compiler-and-lldb/